# Errror recovering mysql data with php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, pdo

i had installed freestyle extension in joomla (to allow php code in articles)  im trying to access to a database in mysql with the next code

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password)

     $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, edad
            FROM Prueba";

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array('%son'));
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
        echo sprintf('%s <br/>', $r['nombre']);
    }
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
```

And i get this error in the article and i dont know why this is happening

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 13

Comment: Have you tested if you have access to all used variables? Pleasy try var_dump($varname) for each variable above the try and check if all variables contain what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password)
```

should be

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

(You're missing a ';')

Also I think your code isn't going to work exactly as planned since your SQL has no variables but you attempt to pass one to `$q->execute()` but I'm sure you can sort out what you're trying to do yourself...

Comment: Thanks a lot, didnt see that, me bad

Comment: Almost every time I see `unexpected T_VARIABLE` it means there's a semicolon missing somewhere...